# Discrete math(greatest common divisor,gcd)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

True or False
For any positive integer,n (n not equal to 13), gcd (13,n)=1.

It might be false if n is a multiple of 13 (e.g. 26) because then the gcd will be 13 instead.But isn't it a precondition that gcd(a,b) means a>b?Thus the statement will be true?

Comment: Your argument on multiples of $13$ is good; $\gcd$ has no precondition about the relative size of the arguments.

Comment: $\gcd (a,b)=\gcd (b,a) $, it doesn't matter if $a>b $ or $b>a $.